# PHP to Python: Moovrelocator

Tags: php, python, video-streaming

I've found library in php called [moovrelocator](http://code.google.com/p/moovrelocator/). 
Description from it's site:
MOOV Relocator is a well documented small library written in PHP to relocate (or move) the MOOV-Atom of MP4-Files from the end to the beginning of a file.

And it works pretty well with php.

Unfortunally I haven't found such library in python. And I want to ask community. Is there any library with which I can replace php-moovrelocator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Quicktime/MP4 Fast Start**](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart)

Enable streaming and pseudo-streaming of Quicktime and MP4 files by
moving metadata and offset information to the front of the file.

**Usage**

> $ qtfaststart.py infile [outfile]